# How to align heights and widths subplot axes with gridspec and matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot, figure, multiple-axes

I am trying to use [matplotlib with gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html) to create a subplot such that the axes are arranged to look similar to the figure below; the figure was taken from [this unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120429/colorbar-as-a-subplot-in-gridspec-python-change-size/57623427#57623427).

[image: Original Image]

My attempt at recreating this axes arrangement is below. **Specifically, my problem is that the axes are not properly aligned.** For example, the axis object for the blue histogram is taller than the axis object for the image with various shades of green; the orange histogram seems to properly align in terms of width, but I attribute this to luck. **How can I properly align these axes?** Unlike the original figure, I would like to add/pad extra empty space between axes such that there borders do not intersect; the slice notation in the code below does this by adding a blank row/column. (In the interest of not making this post longer than it has to be, I did not make the figures "pretty" by playing with axis ticks and the like.)

[image: My attempt]

Unlike the original picture, the axes are not perfectly aligned. Is there a way to do this **without** using constrained layout? By this, I mean some derivative of `fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)`?

The MWE code to recreate my figure is below; note that there was no difference between `ax.imshow(...)` and `ax.matshow(...)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

## initialize figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(6, 6, hspace=0.2, wspace=0.2)
ax_bottom = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:, 2:])
ax_left = fig.add_subplot(gs[:4, :2])
ax_big = fig.add_subplot(gs[:4, 2:])

## generate data
x = np.random.normal(loc=50, scale=10, size=100)
y = np.random.normal(loc=500, scale=50, size=100)

## get singular histograms
x_counts, x_edges = np.histogram(x, bins=np.arange(0, 101, 5))
y_counts, y_edges = np.histogram(y, bins=np.arange(0, 1001, 25))
x_mids = (x_edges[1:] + x_edges[:-1]) / 2
y_mids = (y_edges[1:] + y_edges[:-1]) / 2

## get meshed histogram
sample = np.array([x, y]).T
xy_counts, xy_edges = np.histogramdd(sample, bins=(x_edges, y_edges))

## subplot histogram of x
ax_bottom.bar(x_mids, x_counts,
    width=np.diff(x_edges),
    color='darkorange')
ax_bottom.set_xlim([x_edges[0], x_edges[-1]])
ax_bottom.set_ylim([0, np.max(x_counts)])

## subplot histogram of y
ax_left.bar(y_mids, y_counts,
    width=np.diff(y_edges),
    color='steelblue')
ax_left.set_xlim([y_edges[0], y_edges[-1]])
ax_left.set_ylim([0, np.max(y_counts)])

## subplot histogram of xy-mesh
ax_big.imshow(xy_counts,
    cmap='Greens',
    norm=Normalize(vmin=np.min(xy_counts), vmax=np.max(xy_counts)),
    interpolation='nearest',
    origin='upper')

plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

**EDIT:**

One can initialize the axes by explicitly setting `width_ratios` and `height_ratios` per row/column; this is shown below. This doesn't affect the output, but maybe I'm using it incorrectly?

```
## initialize figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=6, nrows=6, figure=fig, width_ratios=[1]*6, height_ratios=[1]*6)
ax_bottom = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:, 2:])
ax_left = fig.add_subplot(gs[:4, :2])
ax_big = fig.add_subplot(gs[:4, 2:])
```

Comment: When you make your gridspec you may instead want to use height and width ratios rather than slicing into a 6x6 grid.  Gridspec also takes pad arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `imshow`, which resizes the axes automatically to maintain a square pixel aspect.
You can prevent this by calling:

```
ax_big.imshow(..., aspect='auto')
```